# Visio Interop Questions

Tags: c#, interop

I have written a console application which uses UDC (universal document convertor) to convert visio diagrams to an image (more specifically a jpeg).

Everything is working fine (for visio files in 2007 and 2010), and I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio version 14.0.0.0. I thought I would do a test by creating a visio diagram in Visio 2003 and testing the application. It works fine however, I get the following popup "The Microsoft Visio building plan shapes in this drawing must be updated to function in the current version of Visio". If I click "Yes" then the program works fine. This code will eventually be running as a service and I was wondering if there is anyway to supress these warnings? Or tell it to do any conversion automatically?

Answer (score 1):

We seem to have found the answer (trying nearly every property on the Visio.Application class!):

```
vApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application();                
                vApp.Visible = false;
                vApp.Settings.ShowFileOpenWarnings = false;
                vApp.EventsEnabled = 0;
```

It seems the EventsEnabled = 0 did the trick!

Hope this may be useful to someone eventually.. I spent about 4 hours on it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set vApp.AlertResponse = vbYes, which suppresses the dialog and chooses Yes for you.